# Angular Skip to Content only works once

Tags: angular, accessibility

I've added a skip to main link in an Angular application, and it only works once. If you tab back to it and press it again, it navigates you back to the home page. Clicking it a second (overall third) time now brings you to the specified main-content id.

I have tried both of these approaches with varying results.

```
<a class="skipToMain" [routerLink]="[currentURL]" [fragment]="fragment">Skip to content</a>

<button class="skipToMain" (click)="skipToMain()">Skip to content</button>
```

```
fragment: string = 'main-content';

//For the button approach
skipToMain(){
    this.router.navigate([this.router.url], 
   {fragment: this.fragment, relativeTo: this.route, skipLocationChange: true, replaceUrl: false});
}

//For the <a> approach
currentUrl: any = ''
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((e) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (e.url != '') {
          this.currentUrl = e.url;
        } else {
          this.currentUrl ='';
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I have also tried adding in `this.location.replaceState('');` (with the appropriate page url) after the `router.navigate` line in `skipToMain()` but it doesn't seem to do anything, as adding/removing it doesn't change the fact that you keep getting rerouted to the home page on the second button press.

Edit:

I've got a very rough [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-ovksza) that for some reason isn't actually skipping to main like my code is, but it still has the same odd behavior of if you're on the dashboard page and press skip to main twice, you get rerouted to the home page.

I didn't spend much time mocking up the stackblitz, I hope there's not something glaringly obvious that I added/left out, etc.

Edit 2:

I've been able to halfway get it to work by using this now

```
  scrollTo(fragment): void {
    console.log(this.router.url);
    this.router.navigate([], { fragment: fragment }).then(res => {
      const element = document.getElementById(fragment);
      if (element != undefined) element.scrollIntoView();
    });
    // this.location.replaceState(this.currentURL);
    this.location.go(this.currentURL);
  }
```

This prevents it from rerouting to another page, but even though I'm trying to overwrite the URL (and this does work to keep the address bar clear of the skip-link, the actual angular router from `this.router.url` isn't clearing out and going back to the regular page url after routing to the skip-link. How can I clear out the angular router url so that it can navigate to it twice in a row?

Using either one of these (or both) doesn't seem to actually do anything aside from keeping the browser's address bar clear, but internally angular is holding on to the link.

```
this.location.replaceState(this.currentURL);
this.location.go(this.currentURL);
```

Final Edit:

Turns out the easiest way to fix this is to not deal with angular routing at all and scrap all routing and manually focus an element with TS.

```
skipToMain(): void {
    let focusElement = document.querySelectorAll('#main-content')[0] as HTMLElement;
    focusElement.focus();
  }
```

It's not exactly the 'Angular' way of doing things, nor will it likely work well with any page with two+ components that each have a main-content id, so if anyone has any alternatives I'm open to it, but right now for a quick and dirty solution this works fine.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Well a skip link should not navigate to another page. It is linking to an anchor within the same page, like `<a href="#main">` so no logic is necessary in Angular. Is the skip-link really what you are trying to achieve? https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/

Comment: @Andy if I'm on any page other than the home page I get navigated back when using a simple href

Comment: @Chellappan வ Stackblitz added

Comment: You’re `href` simply needs to start with `#` and you do not bind any event handler on it. That’s how the best practice skip link is implemented.